# How to do integration tests for endpoints that use ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have an endpoint that casts the `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse` to `org.springframework.http.ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage`.

```
@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping("/document/{documentId}")
public Mono<Void> serveDocument(@PathVariable final String documentId, final ServerHttpResponse response) {
    final Path documentLocation = fileManipulatorService.newFile(stagingConfigurationProperties.location(), documentId);

    return ((ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage) response)
            .writeWith(documentLocation, 0, fileManipulatorService.size(documentLocation))
            .then(deleteIfExists(documentLocation));
}
```

Usually, this works well but when calling the endpoint with `org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient` the call fails with the following exception:

```
2022-12-30T18:49:07.678+01:00 ERROR 1392 --- [     parallel-1] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [1848ca22]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/document/11c92bad-6fe4-4c85-9d54-4bf4bbad3581"

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpResponse cannot be cast to class org.springframework.http.ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage (org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpResponse and org.springframework.http.ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.github.bottomlessarchive.loa.stage.view.document.controller.StageDocumentController.serveDocument(StageDocumentController.java:53) ~[main/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ? HTTP GET "/document/11c92bad-6fe4-4c85-9d54-4bf4bbad3581" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

This is what my test looks like:

```
@Test
void testServeDocument() {
    final UUID documentId = UUID.randomUUID();
    final byte[] content = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    final Path contentPath = setupFakeFile("/stage/" + documentId, content);
    when(fileManipulatorService.newFile("/stage/", documentId.toString()))
            .thenReturn(contentPath);

    final byte[] responseBody = webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/document/" + documentId)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();

    assertThat(responseBody)
            .isEqualTo(content);
    assertThat(contentPath)
            .doesNotExist();
}
```

For me, everything seems to be right. Is there a reason why MockServerHttpResponse doesn't extend ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage? I wanted to file a bug report to Spring Boot because of this, but before doing so, I came to the conclusion that it might be a better idea to ask first on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the cast for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `MockServerHttpResponse` is a general use mock implementation of a response for tests without an actual server, so it's implemented in a way that is just sufficient and convenient for testing.

Secondly, it doesn't look like any guarantees were ever given that a response in a `ServerWebExchange` must implement `ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage` so I wouldn't blindly cast it without prior type checking.

Another caveat, on Netty even if a response is a `ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage`, the transfer will use zero-byte copy only when the specified path resolves to a local file system `File`, and compression and SSL/TLS are not enabled. Otherwise chunked read/write will be used.
( https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/NettyOutbound.html#sendFile-java.nio.file.Path-long-long- ).

Considering all this I'd refactor your controller to something like this:

```java
@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping("/document/{documentId}")
public Mono<Void> serveDocument(@PathVariable final String documentId, final ServerHttpResponse response) {
    ...
    if (response instanceof ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage zeroCopyHttpOutputMessage) {
        return zeroCopyHttpOutputMessage
                .writeWith(documentLocation, 0, ...)
                ...
    }
    return response
            .writeWith(DataBufferUtils.read(documentLocation, response.bufferFactory(), bufferSize))
            ...
}
```

To test the `ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage` part of this controller in your integration tests you can use a real (non-mocked) web environment and bind your `WebTestClient` to that like so:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class IntegrationTests {
    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer serverPort;

    ...

    @Test
    void testServeDocument() {
        WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToServer()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + serverPort)
                .build();
        
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very valuable info, but... How do I integration test the `response instanceof ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage zeroCopyHttpOutputMessage` part then? It cannot be done as far as I see right?

Comment: In fact it can. See the update.